# How can I access private members in Kotlin when passing a block from one class to another

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda

I've got a class called ClassA, that I'd like to be completely private except for one method that can take in a block of code and execute it. I would like the block of code I pass into this method to be able to call private members of ClassA. This is a heavily simplified representation of what I have now:

```
class ClassA() {  
    private fun printFoo(session: SessionInfo){
        System.out.println("Foo")
    }

    fun runBlock(block: ClassA.() -> Unit) {
        this.block()
    }
}

class ClassB(var classA: ClassA) {    
    fun doThing() {
            classA.runBlock { this.printFoo() }
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't compile because `printFoo` is only private access in ClassA. If I change it's access to public, this code works fine. Is there a way I can reference this `printFoo` in the block I pass in from `ClassB` without having to make the method public?

Comment: Regardless of the fact that I provided an answer, I *need* to ask - why do you want that? Why not simply make fields of `ClassA` public, since you are providing a relatively easy way to access them anyway

Comment: @Fureeish The goal is thread safety. In the actual code, `ClassA` is an important resource that is read and written to by several different threads. My logic is that by forcing all reads/writes to go through `runBlock`, I can synchronize that method and enforce that only one thread at a time can do anything. If you can see any major flaws with this approach, I'd be happy to hear them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways of approaching this: using reflection or a proxy accessor.

#### Using reflection

Reflection will pretty much enable you to do anything you like. You can always force through the hermetization with it:

```
class HasPrivateMembers(private val foo: String)

fun main() {
    val x = HasPrivateMembers("bar")
//    println(x.foo) // doesn't work due to private specifier
    val foo = x.javaClass.getDeclaredField("foo").run {
        isAccessible = true
        get(x) as String
    }.also {
        println(it)
    }
}
```

I wouldn't take this approach though. It feels a little bit hacky and it should feel so. If you were to endorse this approach, you wouldn't be designing an architectural access to your fields. You would be basically indicating that there should be no access to your ields, but if one wishes to interact with them directly anyway (even violate the invariants, if any present), they are free to use the tool that can do that.

This leads us to the second approach.

#### Using proxy accessor object

The idea is to create a `private inner class` that will be used to *delegate* the calls to the API that it shares with `ClassA`:

```
class ClassA {
    private var privateField = "this is private"

    private fun printFoo(){
        println("Foo")
    }

    interface Accessor {
        fun printFoo()
        var privateField: String
    }

    private inner class AccessorImpl : Accessor {
        override fun printFoo() {
            this@ClassA.printFoo()
        }

        override var privateField: String
            get() = this@ClassA.privateField
            set(value) {
                this@ClassA.privateField = value
            }
    }

    fun runBlock(block: Accessor.() -> Unit) {
        AccessorImpl().block()
    }
}

class ClassB(var classA: ClassA) {
    fun doThing() {
        classA.runBlock {
            printFoo()
            privateField = "but I just changed it"
        }
    }
}
```

There are a lot of changes going on here, so let me explain every single one of them for the snippet to make sense:

- `private var privateField = "this is private"` - I added an additional `private` field to demonstrate that the above solution works with data fields too.
- `interface Accessor` - This is the core idea. We have a `public interface` which serves as a glue between the outside world and the private implementation that delegates the access of private fields.
- `private inner class AccessorImpl` - This is the implementation of the core idea.

  - It's `private`, so no one will be able to exploit it and the only way one can use it is via `runBlock()` you provided.
  - It's an `inner class` so its objects hold a reference to the appropriate `ClassA` instance (thus the `this@ClassA` parts).
  - It has the same fields as your `ClassA`, but made `public`.
  - All it does it to delegate *every single operation* to the outer class' object.
- `fun runBlock(block: Accessor.() -> Unit)` - This is the public API for accessing all the `private` fields. Notice that the receiver is an `Accessor`, not `AccessorImpl`. It couldn't be the latter, because it's `private` (for the aforementioned reasons).

  - `AccessorImpl().block()` - We need to create an `Accessor` for the `block` to call on. We need one that will be able to interact with `ClassA`'s `private` fields. Thus we create `AccessorImpl` and call `block()` on it. Keep in mind that `AccessorImpl`, due to being an `inner class`, *knows* that it's bound to the object on which `runBlock()` has been called.

---

While I *strongly* prefer the second solution to the first one, it's good to keep in mind that hermetization shouldn't be violated in normal circumstances. Every time you change private API of `ClassA` (that... does sound weird, but that's what we're dealing with here), you will have to change both `Accessor` and `AccessorImpl` to reflect that. There is no easy workaround around it and frankly I believe that to be a good thing. You should be extra cautious when dealing with such architecture.